# How can I validate a column that is disabled in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I validate using v-validate. But I want it not to validate when it's disabled.I don't want the radio button to validate when the field I select with it is disabled. How can I do this?

```
 <v-col cols="6" v-if="Type =='İhracat '">
                             <v-col cols="12" >
                          <v-text-field
                              v-model="customer.Company"
                              outlined
                              dense
                              label="Unvan"
                              name="Company"
                              :disabled="radios == 'personal' "
                              v-validate="'required'"
                              hide-details="auto"
                              :error="errors.has('Company')"
                              :error-messages="$t(errors.first('Company')?'Unvan Boş Geçilemez':'')"
                          ></v-text-field>
                        </v-col>
                            <v-col cols="6" v-if="Type =='İhracat '">
                              <v-text-field
                                  v-model="customer.LastName"
                                  label="Soyad"
                                  name="LastName"
                                  v-validate="'required'"
                                  :disabled="radios == 'institution'"
                                  hide-details="auto"
                                  :error="errors.has('LastName')"
                                  :error-messages="$t(errors.first('LastName')?'Soyad Boş Geçilemez':'')"
                                  outlined
                                  dense
                              ></v-text-field>
                            </v-col>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a computed value by checking if the radios has the desired value

---

Html

```
:v-validate="validation"
```

---

Computed part

```
validation () {
        return {
            required: this.radios == 'institution'
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're using vuetify, which already integrate validation functionality.

you can use the props "rules" and provide your validations like this

```
<v-text-field
  v-model="customer.Company"
  outlined
  dense
  label="Unvan"
  name="Company"
  :rules="[v => !!v || 'Field required']"
  :disabled="radios == 'personal' "
  hide-details="auto" />
```

The rules props take an array of functions, boolean or string
it needs to return either true / false or a message
I suggest you to make your rules in a constant to be able to reuse it.
You can now put the condition to not validate when your text-field is disabled

```
 const rules = [v => !!v || (!v && radios == 'personal') || 'Field required']
```

For more information, visit https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-text-field/#props
to look at the props informations and samples.